# Is there multi-dimensional spatial pooler for NuPIC?

Tags: nupic, hierarchical-temporal-memory

I'm currently working on some image/video recognition systems. I'd like to build it based on NuPIC. But I cannot find a multi-dimensional spatial pooler, which is very important in the vision domain. Should I implement multi-dimensional SP by myself?

Answer (score 1):

With [this recent change](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/pull/882) to the SP, it now supports any number of dimensions. Just set `inputDimensions` and `columnDimensions` to any number of dimensions you want (make sure they are the same, though), and the SP will respect the topology of the input and column space.